# BIOS passwords: how to choose BIOS Administrator account rather than User account (I set the password the same for both)

Tags: bios

AMI BIOS VERSION: 2.20.1271

Hi,

I set my User password and the Administrator BIOS passwords to identical strings. When I access the BIOS and enter my password, it defaults to the BIOS *User* account.

Is there a way to specify that I am trying to login using the BIOS *Administrator* account? Again, the passwords are the same for both.

Extra Information:
I am unable to flash my BIOS because MSI does not provide a utility to do this on a laptop from outside of the BIOS itself (as far as I can tell given the fact that MSI support has suggested the RMA option as a resolution).

I've disconnected the main battery and CMOS battery inside my MSI GF63 laptop and waited 2 hours in attempt to reset my BIOS settings to no avail.

I can't boot to DOS using a bootable USB drive because my boot settings at the time I set my password prevent this.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this situation.

Comment: Try [this guide](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/cool-websites/reset-bios-password/) to make mistakes intentionally in order to get into the BIOS.

Comment: harrymc- Thanks for the reply. I've been to that site and tried all their recommendations. Unfortunately, when I enter a wrong password 3 times in a row, I don't receive an error code --it just prevents me from trying a 4th time.

Comment: Maybe you should contact MSI Support.

Comment: harrymc- I have contacted MSI support and they have suggested an RMA. I would very, very much like to avoid this option because I cannot be without my laptop (just started a Computer Systems Technology course and it relies very heavily on using it).

Comment: What happens if you press the boot-into-BIOS key during boot?

Comment: If you mean the default key to enter BIOS (in my case DEL), it prompts me for my password. When I enter it, it takes me into BIOS, but I can't change anything, which leads me to believe it is using my password to access the User account rather than the Admin account.

Comment: Try maybe to update the BIOS, even to itself. This might erase the passwords.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't update the BIOS because it has to be done within the BIOS itself and it's only letting me view settings, not change or interact with them.

Comment: No more ideas, sorry.

Comment: Not yet: Some [more ideas](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-reset-remove-clear-or-reveal-cmos-bios-security-password/2/).

Comment: UPDATE: I tried using AUFWIN64 and bricked my laptop, this was not due to advice received here, but my own impatience and stupidity :)

Comment: VTC as non-reproducible because the asker bricked his laptop.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED - Just had this issue myself. Can't promise this solution works for everyone, but it worked for me.

1. Login to BIOS as User.
2. Set User password to blank. (This deactivated User account.)
3. Save, reboot.
   BIOS login should default to Supervisor account.